# Creating DB tables with PHP - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, sql, pdo

**SOLVED**

Hi I'm having trouble creating tables due to this syntax error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in 
>       your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server 
>       version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 11

I've checked the other solutions for this error, but i have yet to resolve it.
I'm wondering if anyone can spot the problem.
My code looks like this:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "myDB";



try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // sql to create table
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    password VARCHAR(256),
    reg_date TIMESTAMP,
    is_author INT(6),
    is_admin INT(6),

    )";
    echo "</br>";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "Table created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the trailing comma after `is_admin`?

Comment: I can't believe it was that easy, thank you so much!